# How to return work order in one particular status and all associated work orders against that asset only?

Tags: oracle, maximo

Hi I have a query to return all open work orders with the following work types (PM, PJ, RD). How do I:

1. Return only PM work orders in WSCH status
2. And if those assets are PMs in WSCH status, then return all open work types (PMs, PJs, RDs) against those assets exclusively.

Any tips for how I would handle this query would be great.

3/3/2022: Edit to include current output and desired output:
[Edit for Current output and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2PVD.jpg)

Sample Query to return all open work orders:

```
SELECT
WO.Asset,
WO.Description,
WO.Status,
WO.Wonum,
WO.Worktype
FROM
Maximo.Workorder WO
WHERE
--Historyflag =0 will bring in all Statuses except Close, (ie COMP, Cancel, WSCH, Inprg, IHP, LO, PH etc)
WO.Historyflag =0 AND
WO.Worktype IN ('PM', 'PJ','RD')
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I cannot help you since I am not sure what do you mean by this: 
"along with all the open work types (PMs, PJs, RDs) against that asset#3374. I don't want to see PMs, PJs, RDs of assets that doesn't have a PM in WSCH status." If you give us more detailed description I think this would be one very easy answer.

Comment: @mstrahinic I edited and added in my current and desired output and brief explanation. I can filter to bring in PM having WSCH status, its the second part to getting associated work orders is where am having problems. Any ideas how I can move forward?

Comment: Can you please send me the query that  you are using to get that first results from new attached file?

Comment: Added query above @mstrahinic

Comment: Now I understand what is the problem with your question. You said : "And if those assets are PMs in WSCH status, then return all open work types (PMs, PJs, RDs) against those assets exclusively."
When you say assets you meant to say returned values from this query. You also have asset on workorder so this makes confusion.